# Static library "interface"

Tags: gcc, mingw, static-libraries

Is there any way to tell the compiler (gcc/mingw32) when building an object file (`lib*.o`) to only expose certain functions from the .c file?
The reason I want to do this is that I am statically linking to a 100,000+ line library (SQLite), but am only using a select few of the functions it offers. I am hoping that if I can tell the compiler to only expose those functions, it will optimize out all the code of the functions that are never needed for those few I selected, thus dratically decreasing the size of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several possible solutions:

This is what I asked about. It is the gcc equivalent of Windows' `dllexpoort`:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html (`-fvisibility`)
- http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

I also discovered link-time code-generation. This allows the linker to see what parts of the code are actually used and get rid of the rest. Using this together with `strip` and `-fwhole-program` has given me drastically better results.

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html (see `-flto` and `-fwhole-program`)

**Note:** This flag only makes sense if you are not compiling the whole program in one call to gcc, which is what I was doing (making a sqlite.o file and then statically linking it in).

The third option which I found but have not yet looked into is mentioned here:

- [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols/6770305#6770305)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the linkers job, not the compilers. When linking that as a program (.exe), the linker will take care of only importing the relevant symbols, and when linking a DLL, the __dllexport mechanism is probably what you are looking for, or some flags of ld can help you (man ld).

Comment: I am using `.so` files, not DLLs. And I think once the source is compiled, the linker can't know which parts are needed by which, and must import the whole thing.