# How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ld, strip

I need to optimize the size of my executable severely (`ARM` development) and
I noticed that in my current build scheme (`gcc` + `ld`) unused symbols are not getting stripped.

The usage of the `arm-strip --strip-unneeded` for the resulting executables / libraries doesn't change the output size of the executable *(I have no idea why, maybe it simply can't)*.

What would be the way *(if it exists)* to modify my building pipeline, so that the unused symbols are stripped from the resulting file?

---

I wouldn't even think of this, but my current embedded environment isn't very "powerful" and 
saving even `500K` out of `2M` results in a very nice loading performance boost.

**Update:**

Unfortunately the current `gcc` version I use doesn't have the `-dead-strip` option and the `-ffunction-sections... + --gc-sections` for `ld` doesn't give any significant difference for the resulting output.

*I'm shocked that this even became a problem, because I was sure that `gcc + ld` should automatically strip unused symbols (why do they even have to keep them?).*

Comment: How do you know that symbols are not used?

Comment: Not referenced anywhere => not being used in the final application. I assume that building call graph while comipling / linking shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the size of the .o file by removing dead *symbols*, or you are trying reduce the size of the actual code footprint once loaded into executable memory?   The fact that you say "embedded" hints at the latter; the question you ask seems focused on the former.

Comment: @Ira I'm trying to reduce the output executable size, because *(as an example)* if I attempt to port some existing applications, which use `boost` libraries, the resulting `.exe` file contains many unused object files and due to the specifications of my current embedded runtime, starting a `10mb` applications takes much longer than, for example, starting a `500k` application.

Comment: @Yippie: You want to get rid of code to minimize load time; the code you want to get rid of are unused methods/etc. from libraries.  Yes, you need to build a call graph to do this.  It isn't that easy; it has to be a global call graph, it has to be conservative (can't remove something that might get used) and has to be accurate (so you have as close to an ideal call graph, so you really know what isn't used).   The big problem is doing a global, accurate call graph.  Don't know of many compilers that do this, let alone linkers.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that they are not referenced anywhere?

Comment: What version of gcc/ld are you using?

Comment: If you upgrade your toolchain (should be pretty straight forward, fear not) possibly Nemos advice will start working?

Comment: Try a LTO build, that often reduces the size of the binary quite a bit.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

For GCC, this is accomplished in two stages:

First compile the data but tell the compiler to separate the code into separate sections within the translation unit. This will be done for functions, classes, and external variables by using the following two compiler flags:

```
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
```

Link the translation units together using the linker optimization flag (this causes the linker to discard unreferenced sections):

```
-Wl,--gc-sections
```

So if you had one file called test.cpp that had two functions declared in it, but one of them was unused, you could omit the unused one with the following command to gcc(g++):

```
gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.cpp -o test -Wl,--gc-sections
```

(Note that -Os is an additional compiler flag that tells GCC to optimize for size)

Comment: Please note this will slow down the executable as per GCC's option descriptions (I tested).

Comment: With `mingw` this does not work when linking statically statically libstdc++ and libgcc with the flag `-static`. The linker option `-strip-all` helps quite a bit, but still the generated executable (or dll) is about 4 way bigger than what Visual Studio would generate. Point is, I have no control on how `libstdc++` was compiled. There should be a `ld` only option.

Answer (score 41):

If [this thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html) is to be believed, you need to supply the [`-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffunction_002dsections-870) to gcc, which will put each function and data object in its own section.  Then you give and [`--gc-sections`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-garbage-collection-175) to GNU ld to remove the unused sections.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I have no idea why, probably the `arm-gcc` compiler issue or something `ARM`-related. If there is something else I could try...

Comment: @Michael: True, but the documentation links I provided are current and seem to support the idea that it should work...  Oh well.

Comment: It's still valid. I've never understood why it's not the default for GCC; I'd even question whether the current default (keep unused symbols) makes any sense.

Comment: @MSalters: It's not the default, because it violates the C and C++ standards.  Suddenly global initialization doesn't happen, which results in some very surprised programmers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Obviously such a symbol is in use if its presence matters. So essentially you're saying that GCC can't properly detect which symbols are actually used?

Comment: @MSalters: You're assuming that initialization has no side-effects.  In C and C++, that is a bad assumption.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Nope, didn't assume that at all. I just observed that _GCC_ assumes that. Did I understand your point correctly, that GCC will also eliminate symbols that are unused _except_ for the side effects of their initialization?

Comment: @MSalters: Only if you pass the non-standard behavior-breaking options, which you proposed to make the default behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Obviously. So I assume that if I'd provide a patch that would properly detect unused symbols, then `-gc-sections` would become the default?

Comment: @MSalters: If you can make a patch that runs static initializers if and only if the side effects are necessary to the correct operation of the program, that would be awesome.  Unfortunately I think doing it perfectly often requires solving the halting problem, so you'll probably need to err on the side of including some extra symbols at times.  Which basically is what Ira says in his comments to the question.  (BTW: "not necessary to the correct operation of the program" is a different definition of "unused" than how that term is used in the standards)

Comment: @BenVoigt in C, global initialization cannot have side-effects (initializers must be constant expressions)

Comment: @Matt: But that's not true in C++... and they share the same linker.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was rebutting your claim "You're assuming that initialization has no side-effects. In C and C++, that is a bad assumption" and the C part of "it violates the C and C++ standards".  How does it allegedly violate the C standard?

Comment: @Matt: After some research I think you're right.  It's a bad assumption only in C++.  I suppose C can get code into the initialization sequence using pragmas and attributes that control sections, but not via initialization.

Comment: OK. A good point about C++ nonetheless. I use these switches in production in C, but had not considered how they might interact with static initialization if I were also to use them in C++.

Answer (score 29):

You'll want to check your docs for your version of gcc & ld:

However for me (OS X gcc 4.0.1) I find these for ld

> ```
> -dead_strip
> ```
>
> Remove functions and data that are unreachable by the entry point or exported symbols.
>
> ```
> -dead_strip_dylibs
> ```
>
> Remove dylibs that are unreachable by the entry point or exported symbols. That is, suppresses the generation of load command commands for dylibs which supplied no symbols during the link. This option should not be used when linking against a dylib which is required at runtime for some indirect reason such as the dylib has an important initializer.

And this helpful option

> ```
> -why_live symbol_name
> ```
>
> Logs a chain of references to symbol_name.  Only applicable with `-dead_strip`.  It can help debug why something that you think should be dead strip removed is not removed.

There's also a note in the gcc/g++ man that certain kinds of dead code elimination are only performed if optimization is enabled when compiling.

While these options/conditions may not hold for your compiler, I suggest you look for something similar in your docs.

Comment: This seems to do nothing with `mingw`.

Comment: `-dead_strip` is not a `gcc` option.

Comment: `-dead_strip` is passed by `gcc` to the linker, but is only supported on Darwin (macOS).

Comment: that's because macOS doesn't have gcc, it has clang. And clang has a compatibility layer you can call as gcc.

Answer (score 26):

Programming habits could help too; e.g. add `static` to functions that are not accessed outside a specific file; use shorter names for symbols (can help a bit, likely not too much); use `const char x[]` where possible; ... [this paper](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), though it talks about dynamic shared objects, can contain suggestions that, if followed, can help to make your final binary output size smaller (if your target is ELF).

Comment: How does it help to choose shorter names for symbols?

Comment: if symbols are not stripped away, ça va sans dire—but it seems it needed to be said now.

Comment: @fuz The paper is talking about dynamic shared objects (eg. `.so` on Linux), so the symbol names have to be retained so that APIs like Python's `ctypes` FFI module can use them to look up symbols by name at runtime.

Answer (score 26):

The answer is `-flto`. You have to pass it to both your compilation and link steps, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

It actually works very well - reduced the size of a microcontroller program I wrote to less than 50% of its previous size!

Unfortunately it did seem a bit buggy - I had instances of things not being built correctly. It may have been due to the build system I'm using (QBS; it's very new), but in any case I'd recommend you only enable it for your final build if possible, and test that build thoroughly.

Comment: "-Wl,--gc-sections" doesn't work on MinGW-W64, "-flto" works for me. Thanks

Comment: The output assembly is very weird with `-flto` I do not understand what it does behind the scene.

Comment: I believe with `-flto` it doesn't compile each file to assembly, it compiles them to LLVM IR, and then the final link compiles them as if they were all in one compilation unit. That means it can eliminate unused functions and inline non-`static` ones, and probably other things too. See https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html

Answer (score 13):

While not strictly about symbols, if going for size - always compile with `-Os` and `-s` flags. `-Os` optimizes the resulting code for minimum executable size and `-s` removes the symbol table and relocation information from the executable.

Sometimes - if small size is desired - playing around with different optimization flags may - or may not - have significance. For example toggling `-ffast-math` and/or `-fomit-frame-pointer` may at times save you even dozens of bytes.

Comment: Most optimization tweaks will still yield correct code as long as you comply with the language standard, but I've had `-ffast-math` wreak havoc in completely standards-compliant C++ code, so I would never recommend it.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to me that the answer provided by Nemo is the correct one. If those instructions do not work, the issue may be related to the version of gcc/ld you're using, as an exercise I compiled an example program using instructions detailed [here](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/removing-unused-functionsdead-codes-with-gccgnu-ld/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void deadcode() { printf("This is d dead codez\n"); }
int main(void) { printf("This is main\n"); return 0 ; }
```

Then I compiled the code using progressively more aggressive dead-code removal switches:

```
gcc -Os test.c -o test.elf
gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.c -o test.elf -Wl,--gc-sections
gcc -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections test.c -o test.elf -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all
```

These compilation and linking parameters produced executables of size 8457, 8164 and 6160 bytes, respectively, the most substantial contribution coming from the 'strip-all' declaration. If you cannot produce similar reductions on your platform,then maybe your version of gcc does not support this functionality. I'm using gcc(4.5.2-8ubuntu4), ld(2.21.0.20110327) on Linux Mint 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64

Answer (score 11):

`strip --strip-unneeded` only operates on the symbol table of your executable. It doesn't actually remove any executable code.

The standard libraries achieve the result you're after by splitting all of their functions into seperate object files, which are combined using `ar`. If you then link the resultant archive as a library (ie. give the option `-l your_library` to ld) then ld will only include the object files, and therefore the symbols, that are actually used.

You may also find some of the responses to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200292/process-for-reducing-the-size-of-a-executable/) of use.

Comment: The separate object files in the library is only relevant when doing a static link.  With shared libraries, the whole library is loaded, but not included in the executable, of course.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this will help with your current predicament as this is a recent feature, but you can specify the visibility of symbols in a global manner. Passing `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden` at compilation can help the linker to later get rid of unneeded symbols. If you're producing an executable (as opposed to a shared library) there's nothing more to do.

More information (and a fine-grained approach for e.g. libraries) is available on [the GCC wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Comment: This requires marking the public symbols as public. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Answer (score 8):

From the GCC 4.2.1 manual, section `-fwhole-program`:

> Assume that the current compilation unit represents whole program being compiled.  All public functions and variables with the exception of `main` and those merged by attribute `externally_visible` become static functions and in a affect gets more aggressively optimized by interprocedural optimizers.  While this option is equivalent to proper use of `static` keyword for programs consisting of single file, in combination with option `--combine` this flag can be used to compile most of smaller scale C programs since the functions and variables become local for the whole combined compilation unit, not for the single source file itself.

Comment: Yeah but that presumably doesn't work with any kind of incremental compilation and is probably going to be a bit slow.

Comment: @Timmmm: I suspect you're thinking of `-flto`.

Comment: Yes! I subsequently found that (why is it not any of the answers?). Unfortunately it seemed a bit buggy, so I'd only recommend it for the final build and then test that build a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**`-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections` minimal example analysis**

These options were mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770305/895245 and I just wanted to confirm that they work and inspect a bit how with `objdump`.

The conclusions we draw similar to what others posts mentioned:

- if any symbol of a section is used, then the entire section goes in, even if some other symbols aren't used at all
- inlining makes a symbol not be considered as used
- `-flto` leads to unused symbols being removed even if other symbols are used in the same compilation unit

**Separate files, `-O3` only**

notmain.c

```
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;

int f1(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int f2(int i) {
    return i + 2;
}
```

main.c

```
extern int i1;
int f1(int i);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return f1(argc) + i1;
}
```

Compile only with `-O3`:

```
gcc -c -O3 notmain.c
gcc -O3 notmain.o main.c
```

Disassemble `notmain.o`:

```
objdump -D notmain.o
```

The output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <f1>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c3                      ret
   8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   f:   00

0000000000000010 <f2>:
  10:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
  14:   8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
  17:   c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <i2>:
   0:   02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
        ...

0000000000000004 <i1>:
   4:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
        ...
```

Disassemble `notmain.o`:

```
objdump -D a.out
```

The output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    1048:       e8 03 01 00 00          call   1150 <f1>
    104d:       03 05 c1 2f 00 00       add    0x2fc1(%rip),%eax        # 4014 <i1>
    1053:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    1057:       c3                      ret
    1058:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    105f:       00

0000000000001150 <f1>:
    1150:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1154:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1157:       c3                      ret
    1158:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    115f:       00

0000000000001160 <f2>:
    1160:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1164:       8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
    1167:       c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000004010 <i2>:
    4010:       02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
        ...

0000000000004014 <i1>:
    4014:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
```

Conclusion both `i2` and `f2` were present in the final output file even though the weren't used.

Even if we had added `-Wl,--gc-sections` to:

```
gcc -O3 -Wl,--gc-sections notmain.o main.c
```

to try and remove unused sections, that wouldn't have changed anything, because in the object file `notmain.o` `i2` appears in the same section as `i1` (`.data`), and `f2` appears in the same section as `f1` (`.text`), which were used and therefore bring their entire sections in the final file.

**`-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections`**

We modify the compilation commands to:

```
gcc -c -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections notmain.c
gcc -O3 -Wl,--gc-sections notmain.o main.c
```

Disassemble `notmain.o`:

```
objdump -D notmain.o
```

Output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text.f1:

0000000000000000 <f1>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .text.f2:

0000000000000000 <f2>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data.i2:

0000000000000000 <i2>:
   0:   02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
        ...

Disassembly of section .data.i1:

0000000000000000 <i1>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
```

So we see how everything gets its own section named based on the symbol name itself.

Disassemble `notmain.o`:

```
objdump -D a.out
```

The output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    1048:       e8 03 01 00 00          call   1150 <f1>
    104d:       03 05 b5 2f 00 00       add    0x2fb5(%rip),%eax        # 4008 <i1>
    1053:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    1057:       c3                      ret
    1058:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    105f:       00

0000000000001150 <f1>:
    1150:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1154:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1157:       c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000004008 <i1>:
    4008:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
```

and it does not contain `i2` nor `f2`. This is because this time every symbol was in its own section, and so `-Wl,--gc-sections` was able to remove every single unused symbol.

**Inlining makes a symbol not be considered as used**

To test the effect of inlining, let's move our test symbols to the same file as `main.c`:

main2.c

```
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;

int f1(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int f2(int i) {
    return i + 2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return f1(argc) + i1;
}
```

And then:

```
gcc -c -O3 main2.c
gcc -O3 -Wl,--gc-sections -o main2.out main2.o
```

Disassemble `main2.o`:

```
objdump -D main2.o
```

The output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <f1>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c3                      ret
   8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   f:   00

0000000000000010 <f2>:
  10:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
  14:   8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
  17:   c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <i2>:
   0:   02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
        ...

0000000000000004 <i1>:
   4:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
        ...

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # a <main+0xa>
   a:   8d 44 38 01             lea    0x1(%rax,%rdi,1),%eax
   e:   c3                      ret
```

Interesting how `main` is on a separate section `.text.startup`, possibly to allow the rest of text to be GC'ed.

We also see that `f1` was fully inlined on `lea 0x1(%rax,%rdi,1),%eax` (directly adds 1), while for reasons I don't understand `i1` is still used at `mov 0x0(%rip),%eax` pending relocation, see also: [What do linkers do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do) The relocation will be clear after disassembling `main2.out` below.

Disassemble `main2.out`:

```
objdump -D main2.out
```

The output contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       8b 05 c2 2f 00 00       mov    0x2fc2(%rip),%eax        # 400c <i1>
    104a:       8d 44 38 01             lea    0x1(%rax,%rdi,1),%eax
    104e:       c3                      ret
    104f:       90                      nop

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000004008 <i2>:
    4008:       02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
        ...

000000000000400c <i1>:
    400c:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
```

and `f1` and `f2` were entirely removed, because `f1` was inlined and therefore not marked as used anymore, so the entire `.text` section got removed.

If we forced `f1` not to be inlined with:

```
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) f1(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

then both `f1` and `f2` would appear on `main2.out`.

**Sections of different object files are separate even though they have the same name**

Obviously, e.g.:

notmain2.c

```
int i3 = 3;
int i4 = 4;

int f3(int i) {
    return i + 3;
}

int f4(int i) {
    return i + 4;
}
```

and then:

```
gcc -c -O3 notmain.c
gcc -c -O3 notmain2.c
gcc -O3 -Wl,--gc-sections notmain.o notmain2.o main.c
objdump -D a.out
```

does not contain `f3` and `f4`, even though `f1` and `f2` were included, and both are no sections called `.text`.

**Possible downside of: `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections`: slower link speed**

We should find some benchmark, but this is likely, as it would require more relocations to be done when one symbol refers to another symbol from the same compilation unit, as they are no present in independent section anymore.

**`-flto` leads to symbols being removed even if other symbols in the same compilation unite are used**

Also, this happens whether or not LTO would lead to inline happening. Consider:

notmain.c

```
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;

int __attribute__ ((noinline)) f1(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int f2(int i) {
    return i + 2;
}
```

main.c

```
extern int i1;
int f1(int i);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return f1(argc) + i1;
}
```

Compile and disassemble:

```
gcc -c -O3 -flto notmain.c
gcc -O3 -flto notmain.o main.c
objdump -D a.out
```

The disassembly contains:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       e8 f7 00 00 00          call   1140 <f1>
    1049:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
    104c:       c3                      ret

0000000000001140 <f1>:
    1140:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1143:       c3                      ret
```

and `f2` is not present. So `f2` was removed even though `f1` is used.

We also note that `i1` and `i2` are gone. The compiler appears to recognize that `i1` is never really modified and just "inlines" it as the constant `1` at: `add $0x1,%eax`.

Related question: [Does GCC LTO perform cross-file dead code elimination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715286/does-gcc-lto-perform-cross-file-dead-code-elimination) For some reason code elimination does not happen if you compile the object file with `-O0`: [Why GCC does not do function dead code elimination with LTO when compiling the object file with -O0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702495/why-gcc-does-not-do-function-dead-code-elimination-with-lto-when-compiling-the-o)

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04 amd64, GCC 12.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy behaviour recommended to build static libraries with all the optional code and to reduce the compilation unit to the minimum necessary to hold a tiny task (recommended also as a pattern in unix design)

When you link the code and specify a static library (a `.a` archive) the linker only processes all the compiled modules that are referenced from the initial `crt0.o` code, and this can be achieved without any section divided compiling code.

We have done this in our code getting a probably not optimum benefit, but allowing us to continue development with a good memory footprint and saving a lot of unused code, but never incurring in issues like making the compiler to investigate that.  I always use this lemma: *if the feature is not necessary, don't tie to it.*

Answer (score -1):

You can use strip binary on object file(eg. executable) to strip all symbols from it.

Note: it changes file itself and don't create copy.