# GCC - don't compile unused code

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel, gcc-warning

When I'm compiling manufacturer's source code for my smartphone kernel, there's a lot of various unused variables/functions warnings. Is there any option to set to GCC/LD to don't compile these unused stuff?

I found solution here [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols) but it conflicts with incremental linking so I can't use it. Any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC's unused variable warning is just that--it's telling you that code declared a variable but didn't use it.  It won't actually compile any code for such a variable, because there is no code to compile, just the declaration.  It's a warning because it's often a symptom of sloppy programming.

Removing linker symbols is a completely unrelated issue, and generally not something you want to to. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: What about global variables? Doesn't they take place in RAM? What about unused functions? Doesn't they increase size of output file?

Comment: Yes (globals), and yes (funtions, but that doesn't generate a warning). If that's what your warnings are about, then you'll just have to fix the code. But in my experience, 99% of those warnings are for locals that got abandoned when code changed.

Comment: Thanks, in my code there are unused static global tables with size of about 60-80B.