# Why GCC --gc-sections and -ffunction-sections is not working? (cmake build)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, ld

I wonder why the GCC compiler flag `-ffunction-sections` and linker flag `--gc-sections` don't eliminate unnecessary resp. unreferenced symbols/functions code from my final executable.
Why is it not working as expected and described in the GCC documentation?

Probably I have overseen some unintended reference !?

Checked already using to this very nice method:
[GCC --gc-sections and finding symbol dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649504/gcc-gc-sections-and-finding-symbol-dependencies) with /DISCARD/ in linker script. No success. There is no reference to my ununsed functions.

No chance to automatically eliminate dead code !? Why ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is quite simple (in my case):

I am using CMake to build my project and it is inserting the flag `-rdynamic` !
To my knowledge the combination of `-rdynamic` and `--gc-sections` options is not mentioned anywhere in the GCC documentation. **There should be a warning like this:**
 **`-rdynamic` renders `--gc-sections` useless bcs. all symbols are implicitly referenced.**

See also: [What exactly does `-rdynamic` do and when exactly is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692315/what-exactly-does-rdynamic-do-and-when-exactly-is-it-needed)

Of course only CMake users are affected by this... (without knowing):

> ### CMP0065
>
> Do not add flags to export symbols from executables without the
>   :prop_tgt:`ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> CMake 3.3 and below, for historical reasons, always linked executables
>   on some platforms with flags like `-rdynamic` to export symbols from
>   the executables for use by any plugins they may load via `dlopen`.
>   CMake 3.4 and above prefer to do this only for executables that are
>   explicitly marked with the :prop_tgt:`ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> The `OLD` behavior of this policy is to always use the additional
>   link flags when linking executables regardless of the value of the
>   :prop_tgt:`ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property.
>
> The `NEW` behavior of this policy is to only use the additional link
>   flags when linking executables if the :prop_tgt:`ENABLE_EXPORTS`
>   target property is set to `True`.
>
> This policy was introduced in CMake version 3.4.  Unlike most
>   policies, CMake version |release| does *not* warn by default when this
>   policy is not set and simply uses OLD behavior.  See documentation of
>   the :variable:`CMAKE_POLICY_WARNING_CMP0065
>   <CMAKE_POLICY_WARNING_CMP<NNNN>>` variable to control the warning.

To get rid of the mostly unnecessary `-rdynamic` CMakeLists.txt just add `cmake_policy(SET CMP0065 NEW)`