# rdynamic blocks garbage collecter --gc-sections

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

according to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283942/1012759

Garbage collector for symbols aka `--gc-sections`  do not work when `rdynamic` is turned on because all symbols are implicitly referenced.

I do use ofc  `-ffunction-sections`, `-fdata-sections` to make `--gc-sections` possible

I need `rdynamic` for pretty prints for calltraces in backtrace. Is there any option to inform compiler to use "rdynamic" only on symbols that are referenced in the code? Or other option that will generate dynamic symbols but only for used functions?

**Problem:** binary size grows because `--gc-section` is blocked by `-rdynamic`, but I need `-rdynamic` for pretty prints in backtraces