# simulating --whole-archive behavior on per symbol basis

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, elf

I am familiar with what the --whole-archive linker option does when using a static archive.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect on a per symbol basis, either via some symbol attributes, or any other trick?

To be clear, lets say I have a .a which has two functions :

```
void foo() {}
void bar() {}
```

I would like to make sure that any executable that was built by linking against this archive will always have the foo() symbol, regardless of whether foo() is being used or not. I do not similarly care about bar()

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe with a linker script?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/File-Commands.html INPUT "For example, if you always want to include subr.o any time you do a link, but you can't be bothered to put it on every link command line, then you can put `INPUT (subr.o)' in your linker script."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to have worked for me.

In a function in my library that I know is always called, I do the following :

```
static volatile auto var = &foo
```

Now, without changing anything in the linking either when creating the archive or building the executable, I see that the executable has the foo symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `-u` for that:

```
gcc -O2 foo.c -o foo -umysymbol -lmylib
```

This forces the linker to treat mysymbol as undefined and resolve it by linking it from the specified libraries.

From the manpage of ld:

> -u symbol
>
> --undefined=symbol
>
> Force symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol. Doing this may, for example, trigger linking of additional
> modules from standard libraries. `-u' may be repeated with different
> option arguments to enter additional undefined symbols.

Comment: --undefined looks good though this means that the final executable's build step needs to be changed. I was hoping to find a way to advertise the public nature of the symbol in the library itself

Comment: @MK I understand, but I fear this will hardly be possible. It always works the other way round, the main binary triggers which symbols are linked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need to modify your linkage to achieve this.

You should be clear that the entities within an archive (`.a`)
that can be linked, or not linked, with your executable are not
individual symbol definitions but individual *archive members*,
which are *object files*, each of which may define arbitrarily
many symbols. If you want to link a symbol from an archive, you link the whole
archive member that defines it.<sup>1</sup>

The foremost difference between linking an archive (`.a`)
with your executable and linking an object file (`.o`) is that
an object file *will* be linked, unconditionally, whereas an archive member
will be linked only if it provides a definition for at least one symbol that 
has been referenced but not defined when the archive is examined.

Hence the ordinary, non-roundabout way of ensuring that a symbol `foo` is linked
unconditionally is to link an *object* file that defines it. There is no
way to mark an archive member `foo.o` as *must be linked* because, if you
*must* link `foo.o`, you do it by linking `foo.o`.

So if `foo` resides in an archive member `foo.o`, you can 
extract that member from the archive:

```
ar x libthing.a foo.o
```

and add `foo.o` to your linkage, even if you don't have the `foo` source
from which to compile `foo.o`.

If there are a lot of functions that you want to link unconditionally
then you might either compile them all from source into a single object
file, if you have the source, or you might collect all the object files
that define them into a single archive that you link with `--whole-archive`.

> I was hoping to find a way to advertise the public nature of the symbol in the library itself

For linkage purposes, there are nothing but public symbols in a library: by
definition any symbols that the linker can see are public.

---

[1] If you are in a position to compile an object file that goes into to
your linkage, then by the use of appropriate compiler and linker flags you
can ensure that redundant symbols it may contribute are finally discarded by
the linker. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770305/1362568)