# Why does the gcc linker behave differently with .a files and .o files?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

Using the example from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc/409470#409470) about the link order in gcc, I tried the following:

```
echo 'extern int b; int a = b;' > b.cpp
g++ -c b.cpp -o b.o
ar cr libb.a b.o

echo 'int b;' > d.cpp
g++ -c d.cpp -o d.o
ar cr libd.a d.o

echo 'extern int a; int main() { return a; }' > a.cpp

g++ a.cpp -o a1 d.o b.o # Works
g++ a.cpp -o a2 libd.a libb.a # Fails
```

If the `.a` file is simply an archive file containing one or several `.o` files, how come linking with the `lib*.a` files (in the wrong order, as stated in the original answer) fails, but using the `.o` files directly (in the same order) works?

Comment: Llibraries are ignored if they don't resolve a symbol, left to right.  A .o file is not ignored.

Comment: @HansPassant: What is the rationale behind this? In the end, only the parts that are needs are kept in the final binary anyway, right? Is there a way to make the behavior with libraries the same as with object files, other than extracting the files from the archive and linking with them directly?

Comment: That's pretty subjective.  In general it is the eternal battle between tool builders and programmers.  Tool builders like to make their tools run fast and not use a lot of memory.  They usually win.  The linker I use doesn't do this, it makes two passes through the .lib files.  But it has an 1-800 support phone number.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the behavior ... the same"? Every part of an object file gets linked into the final executable. Doing that with a library pretty much defeats the purpose of having a library. Imagine going to your local library and asking for a copy of "War and Peace" and having to go home with every book in the library.

Comment: I was under the impression that the linker only kept used parts when building the final binary, but with a couple of further test, I see how every `.o` that I list does in fact get added. My impression was then likely based on the fact that unused _libraries_ were ignored by the linker. Am I right that the gcc linker actually ignores unused `.o` files in the library, and not simply the whole library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the linker is concerned, the difference between a static library and an object file
in the linkage sequence is:-

- An object file is to be linked, just because it is an object file, whether or not it provides 
  definitions of any symbols that the executable needs. If you don't want an object
  file to be linked, don't mention it to the linker.
- A static library is an archive of object files that are to be extracted from the
  library and linked *if required*, where an object file in a library is *required*
  if and only if it provides a definition of at least one hitherto undefined
  symbol that the linker has observed in an object file or library appearing *earlier* in
  the linkage sequence.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So while a library may be just an archive of object files (as it is often described), by using one for linking, we are implicitly telling the linker that we want it to pick only useful object files from it.

Comment: @Masseman Quite so. Though an object file that is linked, even from a library, might define symbols that
are *not* needed as well as symbols that are. You can eliminate such
redundancy, if code size is at a premium, by a [combination of
compiler options and linker options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6687630/1362568)