# How to avoid C runtime (crt*.o) garbage

Tags: c, gcc, crt

I have two C source files

`foo1.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

and `foo2.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void _start(void)
{
    puts("hello world");
    exit(0);
}
```

and I compile them like so on my i386 GNU/Linux platform:

```
$ #compile foo1
$ cc -o foo1 foo1.c
$ #compile foo2
$ cc -S foo2.c
$ as -o foo2.o foo2.s
$ ld -o foo2 -dynamic-linker /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2 -lc foo2.o
$ #notice that crt1.o and others are missing
```

The outputted executables do the same thing from a user's perspective.

```
$ ./foo1
hello world
$ ./foo2
hello world
```

But they are different:

```
$ wc -c foo1
5000
$ wc -c foo2
2208
$ objdump -d foo1 | wc -l
238
$ objdump -d foo2 | wc -l
35
```

Even when I enable gcc's `-Os` option to optimize size,

```
$ #compile foo1
$ gcc -o foo1 foo1.c -Os
```

it is not much smaller:

```
$ wc -c foo1
4908
$ objdump -d foo1 | wc -l
229
```

Is there any way to get GCC to optimize out the parts of `crt1.o` and friends which I suspect contribute to this bloated filesize without resorting to nonstandard code and weird (and likely harmful in some cases) compilation? My GCC's version string is "`gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`".

Comment: Do you have a motivation for wanting to reduce the file size, or is this just purely out of curiosity?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld)

Comment: @EugeneSh. The symbols in the crt _are_ used, but they don't do anything useful in my example case.

Comment: If they don't do anything useful - they are not used.

Comment: And you can always compile without the standard startup code `-nostartfiles`. But then you will have the hassle to replace it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. objdump reveals that at startup code to enable gprof profiling does run, but I will never be using gprof with this binary; in this case useless code is used

Comment: If it can't be removed with the linker as unused, you have no choice but use a different startup code.

Comment: Doesn't work with `gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5` it gives `bash: ./foo2: Accessing a corrupted shared library` I needed to exchange `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2` in the linker command with `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` although the first one links to the second one. Just information if somebody wants to repeat it with an older version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With gcc/clang you can use `-nostartfiles`, but the c library you are using may depend on its own `_start()` implementation for dynamic linking.  Since you are on Linux, I would recommend using a static build of musl-libc.

Alternatively you could just implement the `write()` and `exit()` systemcalls and add the '\n' to your string to avoid the c library altogether by using `_start()` instead of `main()`.   If you need access to argc, argv and envp, you will need some inline assembly to access the stack (Linux passes these on the stack for all ELF binaries regardless of the architecture).

Comment: re: args: [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855)