# gcc configure option explanations

Tags: gcc, linker, libstdc++

I want to investigate a way for my other question ([gcc: Strip unused functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856787/gcc-strip-unused-functions)) by building the latest gcc 6.3.0.

There are some options from https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/configure.html that I would like to try, but don't understand what they meant.

Specifically, these are the flags I want to try:

- `--disable-libstdcxx-verbose`: I rarely use exceptions so I am not very familiar with how it works. I have never seen the "verbose messages" it mentioned before.
- `--enable-linker-build-id` and `--enable-gnu-unique-object`: Simply don't understand what the explanations are trying to say. What are the benefits exactly?
- `--enable-cxx-flags="-ffunction-sections -fstrict-aliasing -fno-exceptions"`: If I use `-fno-exceptions` in libstdc++, doesn't that means I get no exceptions if I use libstdc++? `-ffunction-sections` is used, but where to put `-Wl,-gc-sections`?

Although I always use `--enable-lto`, but with ld.bfd, it seems to be quite useless compared to the famous gold linker.

If you have more flags you think I should try, please let me know!

Comment: Unclear and not related to any of the two different programming languages C or C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> --disable-libstdcxx-verbose: I rarely use exceptions
>   so I am not very familiar with how it works. I have never seen the
>   "verbose messages" it mentioned before.

+1, you normally don't run into [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from) which trigger these friendly error messages you can avoid paying for them.

> --enable-linker-build-id and --enable-gnu-unique-object:
>   Simply don't understand what the explanations are trying to say.
>   What are the benefits exactly?

There are none.

Unique objects is a badly designed feature that prevents shared libraries which contain references to globally used objects (usually vtables) from unloading on `dlclose`. AFAIR it's enabled by default (as it's needed to simulate C++ semantics in shared libs environment).

Build id is needed to support [separate debuginfo](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html).

> --enable-cxx-flags="-ffunction-sections -fstrict-aliasing -fno-exceptions":

You won't benefit from `-fstrict-aliasing` as it's enabled at `-O2` and higher by default.

> -ffunction-sections is used, but where to put -Wl,-gc-sections?

To `--enable-cxx-flags` as well (note that it wants double-dash i.e. `-Wl,--gc-sections`).

> Although I always use --enable-lto, but with ld.bfd,
>   it seems to be quite useless compared to the famous gold linker.

This flags simply enables LTO support in GCC (it's actually equivalent to adding lto to `--enable-languages`). It won't cause any difference unless you enable `-flto` in `CXXFLAGS` as well. Keep in mind that LTO will normally increase executable size (as compiler will have more opportunities for inlining).

> If you have more flags you think I should try, please let me know!

Speaking of size reduction, I'd say `-ffunction-sections` is your best bet (be sure to verify that configure machinery passes all options correctly and libstdc++.a indeed has one section per function). You could also add `-fdata-sections`.

Comment: Turns out `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` are already used for libstdc++ without being specified in `--enable-cxx-flags`. `-Wl,--gc-sections` is unnecessary because no linking steps in libstdc++, I will use this flag when I build my program. Skipped `--enable-linker-build-id` and `--enable-gnu-unique-object`. Did try `--disable-libstdcxx-verbose`. Tested my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856787/gcc-strip-unused-functions again, no improvement. I can only say gcc 6.3.0 + binutils 2.27 perform pretty bad on COFF/PE. if only Windows support ELF.

Comment: "gcc 6.3.0 + binutils 2.27 perform pretty bad on COFF/PE" - yup, that's a fact. Note that unless you somehow inform Cygwin/MinGW developers (and supply them with repro) this isn't going to change.

Comment: I filed a bug at https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/578/ , hope to get some attentions. Thanks for your suggestion!