# Getting a list of archive members used while linking a static library

Tags: c, static-libraries, binutils

Is there a ready-made solution for getting a list of the archive members that got used (or would be used) while linking in an archive (i.e. a static library)?

Say if I have an object file that provides `main` and depends on `a` and `b`. If I link it against a static lib `lib.a`, providing `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in archive members `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o`, and `d.o` respectively, then I would like to get a list with `a.o` and `b.o`, either as a side product of linking the library or by running `command_to_get_members main.o lib.a`

Are there solutions for this or do I need to parse `nm` outputs and resolve the symbols against the archive members manually?

Comment: maybe you looking for this [man ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) or [man strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)

Comment: @Stargateur I think the closest thing to what I'm looking for is passing `-M` to the linker with `-Wl,-M`.  It prints a map that includes a list of how symbols resolve to archive members. Not ideal as I still have to do some text processing on it but I think I'll go with that unless a better solution comes up.

Comment: Oh I better see what you want, indeed nm can do that with --defined-only and --extern-only. Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld. I don't know other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, a script that uses `nm` (with `--defined-only` and `--undefined-only`) to collate which archive objects contain symbols needed by one of the object files specified:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C

objs=()
libs=()
for file in "$@" ; do
    [ -r "$file" ] || continue
    if [ "$file" = "${file%.*}.o" ]; then
        objs+=("$file")
    elif [ "$file" = "${file%.*}.a" ]; then
        libs+=("$file")
    else
        printf '%s: Unknown file type. Skipping.\n' "$file" >&2
    fi
done

nm --defined-only "${libs[@]}" 2>/dev/null | awk -v needsyms="$(nm -u "${objs[@]}" 2>/dev/null | sed -ne 's|^[\t ]*U[\t ]*||p')" \
   'BEGIN {
        split("", objlist)
        n = split(needsyms, symlist)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) need[symlist[i]] = ""
    }
    /\.o:$/ {
        name = $0
        sub(/:$/, "", name)
        next
    }

    (NF >= 3) && ($3 in need) {
        need[$3] = name
        objlist[name] = objlist[name] " " $3
    }

    END {
        # Print symbols found and their source objects:
        # for (name in need) printf "%s: %s\n", need[name], name

        # Print source objects from the archive, with symbols used from it:
        for (name in objlist) printf "%s:%s\n", name, objlist[name]
    }'
```

Files which have a suffix `.a` are considered archive objects providing the symbols, and files with suffix `.o` are object files having undefined symbols.