# CMSIS DSP lookup tables eat up my memory

Tags: memory-management, lookup-tables, cmsis

the CMSIS (Cortex Microcontroller Software Interface Standard) sadly comes with a bulk load of lookup tables. As soon as i use one of its DSP-Functions it includes all the lookup tables (~200KB), even those that I don't need. 
I was wondering if there is a way to tell the gcc or ln to get rid of these unused tables. "arm-eabi-strip --strip-unneeded file.elf" does not seem to do anything. 
I am clueless how to deal with this without manually deleting all these arrays manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer  for my problem here:
[How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld)
Passing -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections to gcc seems to do the trick.