# Possible GCC linker bug causes error when linking weak and local symbols together

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, ld

I'm creating a library and using objcopy to change the visibility of symbols from global to local to avoid exporting a load of internal symbols. If I use the `--undefined` flag to bring in an unused symbol from the library when linking, GCC gives me the following error:

```
`_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_' referenced in section `.text' of ./liblibrary.a(library_stripped.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_[_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_]' of ./liblibrary.a(library_stripped.o)
```

Here are the two source files and makefile that reproduce the issue.

stringstream.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
   std::stringstream messagebuf;
   messagebuf << "Hello world";
   std::cout << messagebuf.str();
   return 0;
}
```

library.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
extern "C" {
void keepme_lib_function() {
    std::stringstream messagebuf;
    messagebuf << "I'm a library function";
    std::cout << messagebuf.str();
}}
```

Makefile:

```
CC = g++

all: executable

#build a test program that uses stringstream
stringstream.o : stringstream.cpp
        $(CC) -g -O0 -o $@ -c $^

#build a library that also uses stringstream
liblibrary.a : library.cpp
        $(CC) -g -O0 -o library.o -c $^
        #Set all symbols to local that aren't intended to be exported (keep-global-symbol doesn't discard anything, just changes the binding value to local)
        objcopy --keep-global-symbol 'keepme_lib_function' library.o library_stripped.o 
        #objcopy --wildcard -W '!keepme_*' library.o library_stripped.o 
        rm -f $@
        ar crs $@ library_stripped.o

#Link the program with the library, and force keepme_lib_function to be kept in, even though it isn't referenced.
executable : clean liblibrary.a stringstream.o
        $(CC) -g -o stringstream stringstream.o -L. -Wl,--undefined=keepme_lib_function,-llibrary # -lgcc_eh -lstdc++ #may need to insert these depending on your environment

clean:
        rm -f library_stripped.o
        rm -f stringstream.o
        rm -f library.o
        rm -f liblibrary.a
        rm -f stringstream
```

If instead of the first objcopy command, I use the second (commented out) one to only weaken the symbols, it works. But I don't want to weaken the symbols, I want them to be local and not visible to people linking to the library at all.

Doing a readelf on the two object files gives the expected result for this symbol. Weak (global) in the program, and local in the library. As far as I know this should link correctly?

library.a:

```
22: 0000000000000000    18 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
```

stringstream.o

```
22: 0000000000000000    18 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    6 _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
```

Is this a bug with GCC, that when I force a function to be brought in from the library, it has already discarded local symbols? Am I doing the right thing by changing symbols to local in my libary?

Comment: Interesting, either using `-u _GLOBAL__sub_I_keepme_lib_function` or swapping the order of `stringstream.o` to go after the archive makes the linking work on my ld (2.26.1)

Comment: Would it be easier (and probably more standard) to use -fvisibility?  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: Thanks Neil, -fvisibility looks interesting, I will have to check if all of the GCC versions that I'm targeting support it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Groundwork**

Let's fill out our knowledge of the offending symbol `_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_` in your
example.

`readelf` reports it identically in both `library.o` and `stringstream.o`:

```
$ readelf -s main.o | grep Bind
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name

$ readelf -s stringstream.o | grep _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
25: 0000000000000000    18 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_

$ readelf -s library.o | grep _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
25: 0000000000000000    18 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
```

So it's a weak function symbol in both object files. It is visible for *dynamic*
linkage (`Vis` = `DEFAULT`) in both files. It's defined in input linkage section #8 (`Ndx` = `8`) in both files.
Note that: *it is defined in both object files*, not just defined in one and maybe referenced
in the other.

What sort of thing could that be? A global inline function. Its inline definition gets into
both object files from one of your headers. `g++` emits weak symbols for
global inline functions to forestall multiple definition errors from the linker:
weak symbols are allowed to be multiply defined in the linkage input (with any number of other
weak definitions and at most one other strong definition).

Let's look at those linkage sections:

```
$ readelf -t stringstream.o
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0x130c0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name
       Type              Address          Offset            Link
       Size              EntSize          Info              Align
       Flags
  ...
  ...
  [ 8] .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000000000001b7  0
       0000000000000012 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000206]: ALLOC, EXEC, GROUP
```

and:

```
$ readelf -t library.o 
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0x130d0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name
       Type              Address          Offset            Link
       Size              EntSize          Info              Align
       Flags
  ...
  ...
  [ 8] .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000000000001bc  0
       0000000000000012 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000206]: ALLOC, EXEC, GROUP
```

They're identical, modulo position. The one notable point here is the section name itself,
`.text._ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_`, which is of the form: `.text.<function_name>`,
and denotes: *A function in the* `text` *(i.e program code) region*.

We'd expect a function to be in the program code, but compare this with, say, your
other function `keepme_lib_function`, which

```
$ readelf -s library.o | grep keepme_lib_function
26: 0000000000000000   246 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 keepme_lib_function
```

tells us is in section #3 of `library.o`. And section #3

```
$ readelf -t library.o
  ...
  ...
  [ 3] .text
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000050  0
       0000000000000154 0000000000000000  0
```

is simply the `.text` section. Not `.text.keepme_lib_function`.

A input section of the form `.text.<function_name>`, like `.text._ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_`,
is a *function-section*. It's a code section that contains *only* the function `<function_name>`.
So in both your `stringstream.o` and `library.o`, the function `_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_`
gets a function-section to itself.

This agrees with `_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_` being an inline global function, and
therefore weakly defined. Suppose a weak symbol has got multiple definitions
in the linkage. Which definition will the linker pick? If any of the definitions
is strong, the linker can allow at most one strong definition and must pick that one.
But what if they're all weak? - which is what we've got here with `_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_`.
In that case, the linker can pick *any one of them*, arbitrarily.

Either way, it will then have to discard all the rejected weak definitions of the symbol from
the linkage. That's what is enabled by putting each weak definition of an inline global function in a function-section
of its own. Then any competing definitions that the linker rejects can be dropped from
the linkage by discarding the function-sections that contain them, with no collateral
damage. That's why `g++` emits those function-sections.

Finally let's identify the function:

```
$ c++filt _ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_
std::operator|(std::_Ios_Openmode, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

We can sleuth for this signature under `/usr/include/c++`, and locate it (for me)
in `/usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h`:

```
inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR _Ios_Openmode
  operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
  { return _Ios_Openmode(static_cast<int>(__a) | static_cast<int>(__b)); }
```

where indeed it is an inline global function, and whence its definition gets into both
your `stringstream.o` and `library.o` via `<iostream>`.

**MVCE**

Now let's make a simpler specimen of your linkage problem.

**a.cpp**

```
inline unsigned foo()
{
    return 0xf0a;
}

unsigned keepme_a() {
    return foo();
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
inline unsigned foo()
{
    return 0xf0b;
}

unsigned keepme_b() {
    return foo();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
extern unsigned keepme_a();
extern unsigned keepme_b();

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << keepme_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << keepme_b() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And a makefile to expedite experiments:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -g -O0
LDFLAGS := -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov',-M=prog.map,--cref

ifdef STRIP
A_OBJ := a_stripped.o
B_OBJ := b_stripped.o
else
A_OBJ := a.o
B_OBJ := b.o
endif

ifdef B_A
OBJS := main.o $(B_OBJ) $(A_OBJ)
else
OBJS := main.o $(A_OBJ) $(B_OBJ)
endif


.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

%_stripped.o: %.o
    objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_$(*)v' $< $@

prog : $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.map prog
```

With this makefile, by default we will link a program `prog` from
untampered-with object files `main.o`, `a.o`, `b.o`, in that order.

If we define `STRIP` on the `make` commandline, we'll replace
`a.o` and `b.o` respectively with the object files `a_stripped.o`
and `b_stripped.o` that have been doctored with:

```
objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_$(*)v' $< $@
```

in which all symbols other than `_Z8keepme_{a|b}v`, (demangled =
`keepme_{a|b}`) have been forced to be `LOCAL`.

Furthermore, if we define `B_A` on the commandline, then the linkage
order of `a[_stripped].o` and `b[_stripped].o` will be reversed.

Notice something about the definitions of the global inline function
`foo` in `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` respectively: they're different. The
former returns `0xf0a` and the latter returns `0xf0b`.

This makes any program we manage to build *illegal* per the C++
Standard: the [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)
stipulates:

> For an inline function ... a definition is required
>   in every translation unit where it is odr-used.

and:

> each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)

That's what the Standard stipulates, but the compiler of course cannot
enforce any constraint on definitions in different translation units,
and the GNU linker, `ld`, is not subject to the C++ Standard, or any language standard.

Let's do some experiments then.

**The default build: make**

```
$ make
g++ -g -O0   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++ -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov' -o prog main.o a.o b.o
a.o: definition of _Z3foov
b.o: reference to _Z3foov
```

Success. And thanks to the linker diagnostic `--trace-symbol='_Z3foov'`,
we're told that the program defines `_Z3foov` (demangled = `foo`)
in `a.o` and references it in `b.o`.

So we input *two different* definitions of `foo` in `a.o` and `b.o`
and in the resulting `prog`, we have just one. The definition in `a.o` was chosen and
the one in `b.o` was ditched.

We can check by running the program, since it can (illegally)
show us which definition of `foo` it calls:

```
$ ./prog
f0a
f0a
```

Yes, `keepme_a()` (from `a.o`) a `keepme_b()` (from `b.o`) are both
calling `foo` from `a.o`.

We've also asked the linker to generate the map file `prog.map`, and
right near the top of that map file we find:

```
Discarded input sections

...
 .text._Z3foov  0x0000000000000000        0xb b.o
...
```

The linker got rid of the `b.o` definition of `foo` by discarding
the function-section `.text._Z3foov` from `b.o`.

**make B_A=Yes**

This time we'll just reverse the linkage order of `a.o` and `b.o`:

```
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.map prog 
$ make B_A=Yes
g++ -g -O0   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov',-M=prog.map,--cref -o prog main.o b.o a.o
b.o: definition of _Z3foov
a.o: reference to _Z3foov
```

Success again. But this time, `_Z3foov` gets its definition from `b.o`
and is only referenced in `a.o`. Check that out:

```
$ ./prog
f0b
f0b
```

And now the map file contains:

```
Discarded input sections

...
 .text._Z3foov  0x0000000000000000        0xb a.o
...
```

The function-section `.text._Z3foov` was this time dropped from `a.o`

**How does that work?**

Well we can see how the GNU linker makes its arbitrary choice between multiple
weak definitions of a global inline function: *it just picks the first definition it finds in the
linkage sequence* and drops the rest. By varying the linkage order
we can get an arbitrary one of the definitions to be linked.

But, if an inline definition must be present in each translation
unit that calls the function, as the Standard *requires*, how is the linker
able to drop the inline definition from any arbitrary one of the translation units and
get an object file that calls the definition inlined in some other one?

The compiler enables the linker to do it. Lets look at the assembly of
`a.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -O0 -S a.cpp && cat a.s 
    .file   "a.cpp"
    .section    .text._Z3foov,"axG",@progbits,_Z3foov,comdat
    .weak   _Z3foov
    .type   _Z3foov, @function
_Z3foov:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $3850, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z3foov, .-_Z3foov
    .text
    .globl  _Z8keepme_av
    .type   _Z8keepme_av, @function
_Z8keepme_av:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    call    _Z3foov
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   _Z8keepme_av, .-_Z8keepme_av
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

There, you see that symbol `_Z3foov` ( = `foo`) is given its function-section
and classified `weak`:

```
    .section    .text._Z3foov,"axG",@progbits,_Z3foov,comdat
    .weak   _Z3foov
```

That symbol is assembled with the inline definition immediately
following:

```
    _Z3foov:
    .LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $3850, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Then in `_Z8keepme_av` ( = `keepme_a`), `foo` is referred to via `_Z3foov`,

```
call    _Z3foov
```

not via the local label `.LFB0` of the inline definition. You'll see the
pattern identically in the assembly of `b.cpp`. Thus, the
function-section containing that inline definition can be discarded from
either `a.o` or `b.o`, and `_Z3foov` resolved to the definition in the
*other* one, and both `keepme_a()` and `keepme_b()` will call the surviving
definition through `_Z3foov` - as we've seen.

So much for experimental successes. Next to experimental failures:

**make STRIP=Yes**

```
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.map prog
$ make STRIP=Yes
g++ -g -O0   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_av' a.o a_stripped.o
g++ -g -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_bv' b.o b_stripped.o
g++ -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov',-M=prog.map,--cref -o prog main.o a_stripped.o b_stripped.o
`_Z3foov' referenced in section `.text' of b_stripped.o: defined in discarded section `.text._Z3foov[_Z3foov]' of b_stripped.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'prog' failed
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

That reproduces your issue. And we have the symmetrical failure also if we reverse the
linkage order:

**make STRIP=Yes B_A=Yes**

```
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.map prog 
$ make STRIP=Yes B_A=Yes
g++ -g -O0   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_bv' b.o b_stripped.o
g++ -g -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
objcopy --keep-global-symbol '_Z8keepme_av' a.o a_stripped.o
g++ -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov',-M=prog.map,--cref -o prog main.o b_stripped.o a_stripped.o
`_Z3foov' referenced in section `.text' of a_stripped.o: defined in discarded section `.text._Z3foov[_Z3foov]' of a_stripped.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'prog' failed
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

**Why is that?**

As you might now already see, it's because the `objcopy` intervention
creates an insoluble problem for the linker, as you can observe after
that last `make`:

```
$ readelf -s a_stripped.o | grep _Z3foov
16: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 _Z3foov

$ readelf -s b_stripped.o | grep _Z3foov
16: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 _Z3foov
```

The symbol still has a definition in `a_stripped.o` and also in `b_stripped.o`,
but the definitions are now `LOCAL`, not available to satisfy external
references from other object files. Both definitions are in input section `#6`:

```
$ readelf -t a_stripped.o
  ...
  ...
  [ 6] .text._Z3foov
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000053  0
       000000000000000b 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000206]: ALLOC, EXEC, GROUP


$ readelf -t b_stripped.o
  ...
  ...
[ 6] .text._Z3foov
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000053  0
       000000000000000b 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000206]: ALLOC, EXEC, GROUP
```

which in each case remains a function-section `.text._Z3foov`

The linker can retain only one of the input `.text._Z3foov` function-sections
for output in the `.text` section of `prog` and must discard the rest, to
avert multiple definitions of `_Z3foov`. So it ticks the second-comer of those
input sections, whether in `a_stripped.o` or `b_stripped.o`, to be discarded.

Say it's `b_stripped.o` that comes second. Our `objcopy` intervention has made `_Z3foov` *local* 
in both object files. So in `keepme_b()` the call to `foo()` can now *only* be resolved by
the local definition - the one that's assembled after label `.LFB0` in the assembly -
which is in the `.text._Z3foov` function-section of `b_stripped.o` that is scheduled
to be discarded. So that reference to `foo()` in `b_stripped.o` cannot be resolved in the program:

```
`_Z3foov' referenced in section `.text' of b_stripped.o: defined in discarded section `.text._Z3foov[_Z3foov]' of b_stripped.o
```

That's the explanation of your issue.

**But...**

... you might say: Isn't it an oversight on the linker's part not to check,
before it decides to discard a function-section, if that section actually contains
any a global function definition that might possibly collide with others?

You could argue that, but not very persuasively. Function-sections are things that
only compilers create in the real world, and they are created for only two reasons:-

- To let the linker discard global functions that aren't called by the program, without
  collateral damage.
- To let the linker discard rejected surplus definitions of global inline functions,
  without collateral damage.

So it's reasonable for the linker to operate on the assumption that a function-section
only exists to contain a definition of a global function.

A compiler will never trouble the linker with the scenario you've engineered,
because a compiler just won't emit linkage sections that contain
only local symbols. In our MCVE, we've got the option of making `foo` a local
symbol in either `a.o` or `b.o` or both without going behind the compiler's
back. We can either make it a `static` function or, more C++-ishly,
we can put it in an anonymous namespace. For a final experiment, let's do
that:

**a.cpp (reprise)**

```
namespace {

inline unsigned foo()
{
    return 0xf0a;
}

}

unsigned keepme_a() {
    return foo();
}
```

**b.cpp (reprise)**

```
namespace {

inline unsigned foo()
{
    return 0xf0b;
}

}

unsigned keepme_b() {
    return foo();
}
```

Build and run:

```
$ make && ./prog
g++ -g -O0   -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -g -O0   -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++ -g -L. -Wl,--trace-symbol='_Z3foov',-M=prog.map,--cref -o prog main.o a.o b.o
f0a
f0b
```

Now naturally, `keepme_a()` and `keepme_b()` each call their local definition
of `foo`, and:

```
$ nm -s a.o
000000000000000b T _Z8keepme_av
0000000000000000 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv
$ nm -s b.o
000000000000000b T _Z8keepme_bv
0000000000000000 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv
```

`_Z3foov` is gone from the global symbol tables<sup>1</sup>, and:

```
$ echo \[$(readelf -t a.o | grep '.text._Z3foov')\]
[]
$ echo \[$(readelf -t b.o | grep '.text._Z3foov')\]
[]
```

the function-section `.text._Z3foov` is gone from both object files. The linker never knows of these local `foo`s existence.

You don't have the option of getting `g++` to make `_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_`
( = `std::operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b`) a local symbol
in your implementation of the Standard C++ library short of hacking
`ios_base.h`, which of course you wouldn't.

But what you were trying to do was *hack the linkage* of this symbol
from the Standard C++ library to make it local in one translation
unit within your program and weakly global in another, and you blind-sided
the linker, and yourself.

**So...**

> Am I doing the right thing by changing symbols to local in my library?

No. Not unless they are symbols whose definitions *you* control,
in your code, and then if you want them made local, make them local
in the source code using one the language facilities for the purpose,
and let the compiler take care of the object code.

If you want to further minimise symbol bloat, see [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687630/1362568)
Safe techniques allow the *compiler* to produce the lean object files
that are linked, and/or allow the *linker* to pare fat, or at least
operate on the linked binary, post linkage.

Tampering with the object files *between* the compiler and the linker
is tampering at your peril, and never more so than if its tampering
with the linkage of external library symbols.

---

[1] `_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv` (demangled = `(anonymous namespace)::foo()`)
has appeared, but it's local (`t`) not global (`T`) and is only
in the symbol table at all because we're compiling with `-O0`.

Comment: Wow, this might be the most comprehensive answer I've ever seen. Thank you so much! It really explains everything I needed!