# Why unused objects in STATIC lib included in final binary when SHARED lib reference them?

Tags: c, unix, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

**Summary:**

Cross used function between STATIC and SHARED lib lead to have all objects of STATIC lib (even unused!) to be included in final binary!

You don't understand what I mean I suppose ? **:-p**

Sit and read the full story below !
Name have been change to protect the innocent. Example's target was simplicity and reproducibility.

Teaser : there's a **SSCCE** available!   ( Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example  : http://www.sscce.org/ )

At beginning, I had :

- a binary (`main`) calling a function (`fun1a()`) stored in a STATIC lib (`libsub.a`).  `main` also have an internal function (`mainsub()`).
- a STATIC lib (`libsub.a`) that is containing *SEVERAL* objects each with several functions used by other sources.

Compiling `main` result in a binary having *ONLY* a copy of the object(s) (STATIC lib) containing the referenced functions.
In the example below, `main` will only contain functions of object `shared1.o` (because main is calling `func1a()` )  and *NOT* functions of `shared2.o` (because no references).

OK !

```
  main.c                 libsub.a    
+-------------+        +------------+
| main        |        | shared1.o  |
|  func1a()   | <----> |   func1a() |
|  mainsub()  |        |   func1b() |
+-------------+        |    ----    |
                       | shared2.o  |
                       |   func2a() |
                       |   func2b() |
                       +------------+
```

As an improvement, I wanted to allow 'external' people to be able to overwrite functions called in `main` by *their own code*, without having to recompile *MY* binary.

I didn't provide source anyway, nor my static lib.

To do so, I intended to provide a "ready to fill" function skeleton source. (That's called a USER-EXIT ?! )
The use of SHARED / DYNAMIC lib could do that IMHO.
The functions that could be overwritten, are either internal to main (`mainsub()`)  or shared functions (`func1a()` ...) and would be stored in shared lib (.so) to be added/referenced during link.

New sources were created, prefixed with 'c', that would contain the 'Client' version of the 'standard' functions.
The switch of using (or not) overwritten function is out of scope. Just take as is that if `UE` is true, then overwritten is made.

`cmain.c` is a new source containing `Client_mainsub()` that could be called 'in replacement' of `mainsub()`

`cshared1.c` is a new source containing `Client_func1a()` that could be called 'in replacement' of `func1a()`. *Indeed all functions in `shared1.c` could have their replacement in `cshared1.c`*

`cshared2.c` is a new source containing `Client_func2a()` that could be called 'in replacement' of `func2a()`

The overview becomes :

```
     main.c                          libsub.a                       clibsub.so
   +-----------------------+     +------------------------+     +--------------------+
   | main                  |     | shared1.o              |     | cshared1.o         |
   |  func1a() {}          |     |   func1a()             |     |   Client_func1a()  |
   |  mainsub()            | <-> |   { if UE              | <-> |    {do ur stuff }  |
   |  { if UE              |     |     Client_func1a()    |     |                    |
   |     Client_mainsub()  |     |     return           } |     | cshared2.o         |
   |     return           }|     |   func1b()             |     |   Client_func2a()  |
   +-----------------------+     |        -------         |    >|    {do ur stuff }  |
                ^                | shared2.o              |   / +--------------------+
    cmain.c     v                |   func2a()             |  /
   +--------------------+        |   { if UE              | /
   | cmain              |        |     Client_func2a()    |<
   |   Client_mainsub() |        |     return           } |
   |    {do ur stuff }  |        |   func2b()             |
   +--------------------+        +------------------------+
```

Here again, as `main` do not call `func2a()` nor `func2b()`, the (STATIC) object shared2.o is not included in the binary, and no reference to (SHARED) `Client_func2a()` exist either. 
OK !

---

Finally, simply overwriting functions was not enough (or too much !).
I wanted external people to be able to call my function (or not) ... but *ALSO* allow them to do some stuff right *BEFORE* and/or right *AFTER* my function.

So instead of having `func2a()` stupidly replaced by `Client_func2a()`, we would have roughly in pseudo code:

```
       shared2.c              |          cshared2.c
                    (assume UE=true)
                              |
func2a()  {                   |Client_func2a() {
    if UE {}                  |
        Client_func2a()      ==>    do (or not) some stuf PRE call
                              |
                              |     if (DOIT)  {            // activate or not standard call
                              |         UE=false 
                              |         func2a()            // do standard stuff
                              |         UE=true
                              |     } else  
                              |     {   do ur bespoke stuff }
                              |     
                              |     do (or not) some stuf POST call
                              | }
                             <==
    } else
      { do standard stuff }
}
```

Remember that `cshared2.c` is provided to other people that could (or not) do their own stuff on the provided skeleton.

*(Note : Setting `UE` to false and back to true in `Client_func2a()` avoids infinite loop in `func2a()` call ! ;-) )*

Now comes my problem.

In that case, the result binary now includes `shared2.o` object despite *NO* call is made in main to any function of `shared2.c` nor `cshared2.c` !!!!!

After searching this looks to be because of the cross calls/reference :

```
shared2.o contains func2a() that may call Client_func2a()
cshared2.o contains Client_func2a() that may call func2a()
```

So why `main` binary is containing shared2.o ?

```
>dump -Tv main

main:

                        ***Loader Section***

                        ***Loader Symbol Table Information***
[Index]      Value      Scn     IMEX Sclass   Type           IMPid Name

[0]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     RW EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) errno
[1]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) __mod_init
[2]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) exit
[3]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) printf
[4]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     RW EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) __n_pthreads
[5]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     RW EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) __crt0v
[6]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     RW EXTref libc.a(shr_64.o) __malloc_user_defined_name
[7]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref     libcmain.so Client_mainsub1
[8]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref   libcshared.so Client_func1b
[9]     0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref   libcshared.so Client_func1a
[10]    0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref   libcshared.so Client_func2b          <<< but why ??? ok bcoz func2b() is referenced ...
[11]    0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref   libcshared.so Client_func2a          <<< but why ??? ok bcoz func2a() is referenced ...
[12]    0x110000b50    .data    ENTpt     DS SECdef        [noIMid] __start
[13]    0x110000b78    .data      EXP     DS SECdef        [noIMid] func1a
[14]    0x110000b90    .data      EXP     DS SECdef        [noIMid] func1b
[15]    0x110000ba8    .data      EXP     DS SECdef        [noIMid] func2b                <<< but why this ? Not a single call is made in main ???
[16]    0x110000bc0    .data      EXP     DS SECdef        [noIMid] func2a                <<< but why this ? Not a single call is made in main ???
```

Note that simply putting in comment `func2a()` ( and `func2b()` ) solves the link issue (breaking the cross)... but it's not possible as I would like to keep a shared lib !?

The behavior is happening on AIX 7.1 with IBM XL C/C++ 12.1 , but it looks to be the same on Linux (Red Hat 5 + GCC 5.4 with some small changed in compilation param)

```
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1 (5765-J02, 5725-C72)
Version: 12.01.0000.0000
Driver Version: 12.01(C/C++) Level: 120315
C Front End Version: 12.01(C/C++) Level: 120322
High-Level Optimizer Version: 12.01(C/C++) and 14.01(Fortran) Level: 120315
Low-Level Optimizer Version: 12.01(C/C++) and 14.01(Fortran) Level: 120321
```

So I figure out this is surely a misunderstanding. Can anyone explain ?

---

As promised here are the SSCCE. 
You can replay my problem by recreating/downloading the following small files and run go.sh (see comment inside the script)

**Edit1** : added code into the question, not on external site as suggested

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

extern void func1a (), func1b ();

int UEXIT(char* file, char* func)
{
    printf("      UEXIT file=<%s>   func=<%s>\n",file,func);
    return 1;   /* always true for testing */
}


main (){
    printf(">>> main\n");
    func1a ();
    mainsub ();
    printf("<<< main\n");
}

mainsub () {
    printf(">>> mainsub\n");

    if(UEXIT("main","mainsub")) {
        Client_mainsub1();
        return;
    }
    printf("<<< mainsub\n");
}
```

**cmain.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

void Client_mainsub1 () {
    printf(">>>>>> Client_mainsub1\n");
    printf("<<<<<< Client_mainsub1\n");
return;
}
```

**inc.h**

```
extern int UEXIT(char * fileName, char * functionName);
```

**shared1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

void func1a (){
    printf(">>>>> func1a\n");
    if(UEXIT("main","func1a")) {
        Client_func1a();
        return;
    }
    printf("<<<<< func1a\n");
}

void func1b (){
    printf(">>>>> func1b\n");
    if(UEXIT("main","func1b")){
        Client_func1b();
        return;
    }
    printf("<<<<< func1b\n");
}
```

**shared2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

void func2a (){
    printf(">>>>> func2a\n");
    if(UEXIT("main","func2a")) {
        Client_func2a();
        return;
    }
    printf("<<<<< func2a\n");
}

void func2b (){
    printf(">>>>> func2b\n");
    if(UEXIT("main","func2b")){
        Client_func2b();
        return;
    }
    printf("<<<<< func2b\n");
}
```

**cshared1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

void Client_func1a () {
    int standardFunctionCall = 0;
    printf("\t>>>> Client_func1a\n");
    if (standardFunctionCall) {
        func1a();
    }
    printf("\t<<< Client_func1a\n");
    return;
}


void Client_func1b () {
    int standardFunctionCall = 0;
    printf("\t>>>> Client_func1b\n");
    if (standardFunctionCall) {
        func1b();
    }
    printf("\t<<< Client_func1b\n");
    return;
}
```

**cshared2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inc.h"

void Client_func2a () {
    int standardFunctionCall = 0;
    printf("\t>>>> Client_func2a\n");
    if (standardFunctionCall) {
        func2a();           /* !!!!!! comment this to avoid crossed link with shared2.c !!!!! */
    }
    printf("\t<<< Client_func2a\n");
    return;
}


void Client_func2b () {
    int standardFunctionCall = 0;
    printf("\t>>>> Client_func2b\n");
    if (standardFunctionCall) {
        func2b();           /* !!!!!! ALSO comment this to avoid crossed link with shared2.c !!!!! */
    }
    printf("\t<<< Client_func2b\n");
    return;
}
```

**go.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

## usage :
## . ./go.sh
## so that the redefinition of LIBPATH is propagated to calling ENV ...
##    otherwise :  "Dependent module libcshared.so could not be loaded."


# default OBJECT_MODE to 64 bit (avoid explicitely setting -X64 options...)
export OBJECT_MODE=64
export LIBPATH=.:$LIBPATH

# Compile client functions for target binary
cc -q64 -c -o cmain.o cmain.c

# (1) Shared lib for internal function
cc -G -q64 -o libcmain.so cmain.o


# Compile common functions
cc -c shared2.c shared1.c

# Compile client common functions overwrite
cc -c cshared2.c cshared1.c


# (2) Built libsub.a for common functions (STATIC)
ar -rv libsub.a  shared1.o shared2.o

# (3) Built libcshared.so for client common functions overwrite (SHARED)
cc -G -q64 -o libcshared.so cshared1.o cshared2.o


# Finally built binary using above (1) (2) (3)
# main only call func1a() , so should only include objects shared1
# But pragmatically shared2 is also included if cshared2 reference a possible call to func2() in shared2 !!!!????
#   Check this with "nm main |grep shared2" or "nm main |grep func2" or "dump -Tv main |grep func2"
cc -q64 -o main main.c -bstatic libsub.a -bshared libcmain.so  libcshared.so

# result is the same without specifying -bstatic or -bshared
#cc -q64 -o main2 main.c libsub.a libcmain.so  libcshared.so


#If I split libcshared.so into libcshared1.so and libcshared2.so it is also the same :
#cc -G -q64 -o libcshared1.so cshared1.o
#cc -G -q64 -o libcshared2.so cshared2.o
#cc -q64 -o main4 main.c -bstatic libsub.a -bshared libcmain.so  libcshared1.so libcshared2.so

#If I do not inlcude libcshared2.so, binary is of course well working, without reference to cshared2 nor shared2 . 
# So why linker chooses to add STATIC shared2.o only if libcshared2.so is listed ?
# Is there a way to avoid this add of unused code ?
#cc -q64 -o main4 main.c -bstatic libsub.a -bshared libcmain.so  libcshared1.so
```

**Edit2** : added RedHat version of go.sh script as requested

**gored.sh**

```
## usage :
## . ./gored.sh
## so that the redefinition of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is propagated to calling ENV ...
##    otherwise :  "Dependent module libcshared.so could not be loaded."
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Compile client functions for target binary
gcc -fPIC -c cmain.c

# (1) Shared lib for internal function
gcc -shared -o libcmain.so cmain.o


# Compile common functions
gcc -c shared2.c shared1.c

# Compile client common functions overwrite
gcc -fPIC -c cshared2.c cshared1.c


# (2) Built libsub.a for common functions (STATIC)
ar -rv libsub.a  shared1.o shared2.o

# (3) Built libcshared.so for client common functions overwrite (SHARED)
gcc -shared -o libcshared.so cshared1.o cshared2.o


# Finally built binary using above (1) (2) (3)
# main only call func1a() , so should only include objects shared1
# But pragmatically shared2 is also included if cshared2 reference a possible call to func2() in shared2 !!!!????
#   Check this with "nm main |grep shared2" or "nm main |grep func2" or "dump -Tv main |grep func2"
gcc -o main main.c libcmain.so  libcshared.so libsub.a

#If I split libcshared.so into libcshared1.so and libcshared2.so it is also the same :
gcc -shared -o libcshared1.so cshared1.o
gcc -shared -o libcshared2.so cshared2.o
cc -o main2 main.c libcmain.so  libcshared1.so libcshared2.so libsub.a

#If I do not inlcude libcshared2.so, binary is of course well working, without reference to cshared2 nor shared2 . 
# So why linker chooses to add STATIC shared2.o only if libcshared2.so is listed ?
# Is there a way to avoid this add of unused code ?
cc -o main3 main.c libcmain.so  libcshared1.so libsub.a
```

Or here the full above files (without gored.sh) in a single .tar.bz2. (6KB).

https://pastebin.com/KsaqacAu

Just copy/paste in a new file (ex `poc.uue`). Then type

```
uudecode poc.uue
```

and you should get  **poc.tar.bz2**

unzip, untar go into poc folder and run

```
. ./go.sh
```

then

```
dump -Tv main
```

or if under RedHat

```
nm main
```

example of result after `gored.sh` :

```
poc>nm main |grep func2
*                 U Client_func2a
                 U Client_func2b
0000000000400924 T func2a
000000000040095d T func2b
poc>nm main2 |grep func2
                 U Client_func2a
                 U Client_func2b
0000000000400934 T func2a
000000000040096d T func2b
poc>nm main3 |grep func2
poc>
```

---

**Edit3: ASCII ART ! :-)**
Here's the 'visual' final state with unused objects/references I think the linker is wrong to include. Or at least not smart enough to detect as unused.
Maybe that's normal or there's an option to avoid having unused static code in final binary. This doesn't look as a complex situation as the surounded tagged 'UNUSED !?' code is linked with nothing ? Isn't it ?

```
     main.c                          libsub.a                                clibsub.so                          
   +-----------------------+       +-------------------------+           +-----------------------------+         
   | main                  |       | +---------------------+ |           | +-------------------------+ |         
   |  func1a();  <-------------\   | |shared1.o            | |           | | cshared1.o              | |         
   |  mainsub()            |    \------>func1a() { <-------------+     /-----> Client_func1a() {     | |         
   |  { if UE {            |       | |   if UE {           | |   |    /  | |      PRE-stuff          | |         
   |     Client_mainsub()  |       | |     Client_func1a() <-----C---/   | |      if (DOIT) {        | |         
   |     return  ^         |       | |     return          | |   |       | |        UE=false         | |         
   |    }        |         |       | |   } else {          | |   +----------------> func1a()         | |         
   |  }          |         |       | |     do std stuff    | |           | |        UE=true          | |         
   +-------------|---------+       | |   }                 | |           | |      } else {           | |         
                 |                 | |                     | |           | |        do bespoke stuff | |         
                 |                 | |  func1b() {         | |           | |      }                  | |         
                 |                 | |     same as above   | |           | |      POST-stuff         | |         
                 |                 | |  }                  | |           | |   }                     | |         
                 |                 | +---------------------+ |           | |   Client_func1b() {}    | |         
                 |                 |                         |           | +-------------------------+ |         
                 |              ***|*******U*N*U*S*E*D**?!***|*****U*N*U*S*E*D**?!*******U*N*U*S*E*D**?!****     
                 |              *  | +---------------------+ |           | +-------------------------+ |   *     
                 |              U  | |shared2.o            | |           | | cshared2.o              | |   U     
                 |              *  | |  func2a() { <-------------+     /-----> Client_func2a() {     | |   *     
                 |              N  | |   if UE {           | |   |    /  | |      PRE-stuff          | |   N     
    cmain.so     |              *  | |     Client_func2a())<-----C---/   | |      if (DOIT) {        | |   *     
   +-------------|------+       U  | |     return          | |   |       | |        UE=false         | |   U     
   | cmain.o     v      |       *  | |   } else {          | |   +----------------> func2a()         | |   *     
   |   Client_mainsub() |       S  | |     do std stuff    | |           | |        UE=true          | |   S     
   |    {do ur stuff }  |       *  | |   }                 | |           | |      } else {           | |   *     
   +--------------------+       E  | |                     | |           | |        do bespoke stuff | |   E     
                                *  | |  func2b() {         | |           | |      }                  | |   *     
                                D  | |     same as above   | |           | |      POST-stuff         | |   D     
                                *  | |  }                  | |           | |   Client_func2b() {}    | |   *     
                                *  | +---------------------+ |           | +-------------------------+ |   *     
                                ?  +-------------------------+           +---------------------------+ |   ?     
                                !                                                                          !     
                                *********U*N*U*S*E*D**?!*************U*N*U*S*E*D**?!******U*N*U*S*E*D**?!***
```

Any constructive answer to put me on the right way is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You have clearly devoted considerable effort to preparing this question, and we appreciate that.  Please understand, however, that we answer questions here not only for those who pose them, but also for the benefit of others who have similar questions later.  Therefore, we require that sufficient code and data to reproduce the problem be presented *in the question itself*, not via reference to external sites.  In case you are inclined to update your question to comply, I will add that I think the essential linking issue you ask about can probably be modeled with less code.

Comment: Indeed I have thought that putting my test case into the message itself would create a bloatty message (2 or 3 times its size). But go for it ! :-)

Comment: As a start, try options `-bnoexpall` and `-bnoexpfull` when creating the main executable.

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond : Tried both. No improvement. (Note : according to ld's man, these are the default values !?). Thx anyway !

Comment: Please post a RedHat version of `go.sh`. Very few readers can readily access IBM XL C/C++.

Comment: Well, libcshared.so _does_ have unresolved externs: func1a, func1b, func2a, func2b. From where do you intend them to be resolved?

Comment: @Mike Kinghan : gored.sh script for RedHat added + result of nm.

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond : I understand that the linker tries to resolv `func2a` and `func2b` in `cshared2.o` (`libcshared.so`) and that he found them in `shared2.o` (`libsub.a`). But isn't it smart enough **NOT** to include them both, as none is referenced by main ? I've updated another time the question to insert an ASCII art of the final state to have a visual of the situation. It may help ?

Comment: Well, a _shared library_ is actually a _shared object:_ the linker handles it as an object (unit), not as a library: it doesn't use parts of the shared object, it includes it as a whole. Then it resolves _every_ externals of it.

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond : thx for pointing the shared lib is considered as a whole. This makes me understand the linker result! Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a much simplified illustration of the linker behaviour that is puzzling
you:

**main.c**

```
extern void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void do_bar(void);

void bar(void)
{
    do_bar();
}
```

**do_bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_bar(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

Let's compile all those source files to object files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c foo.c bar.c do_bar.c
```

Now we'll try to link a program, like so:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o foo.o bar.o
bar.o: In function `bar':
bar.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `do_bar'
```

The undefined function `do_bar` is referenced only in the definition
of `bar`, and `bar` is not referenced in
the program at all. Why then the linkage failure?

Quite simply, this linkage failed because *we told the linker to link* `bar.o`
*into the program*; so it did; and `bar.o` contains the definition of `bar`,
which references `do_bar`, which is not defined in the linkage. `bar` is not
referenced, but `do_bar` *is* - by `bar`, which is linked in the program.

By default, the linker demands that any symbol that is referenced in the linkage
of a program is defined in the linkage. If we compel it to link the definition
of `bar`, then it will demand a definition of `do_bar`, because without a
definition of `do_bar` it hasn't actually *got* a definition of `bar`. It if links
a definition of `bar`, it does not question whether we *need* to link it,
and then permit undefined references to `do_bar` if the answer is No.

The linkage failure is course fixable with:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o foo.o bar.o do_bar.o
$ ./prog
foo
```

Now in this illustration, linking `bar.o` in the program is simply gratuitous. We
can also link successfully just by *not* telling the linker to link `bar.o`.

```
gcc -o prog main.o foo.o
$ ./prog
foo
```

`bar.o` and `do_bar.o` are both are superfluous for
executing `main`, but the program can only be linked with both, or with neither

But suppose `foo` and `bar` were defined in the same file?

They might be defined in the same object file, `foobar.o`:

```
ld -r -o foobar.o foo.o bar.o
```

And then:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o foobar.o
foobar.o: In function `bar':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `do_bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, the linker cannot link the definition of `foo` without also linking the
definition of `bar`. So once again, we have to link a definition of `do_bar`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o foobar.o do_bar.o
$ ./prog
foo
```

Linked like this, `prog` contains definitions of `foo`, `bar` and `do_bar`:

```
$ nm prog | grep -e foo -e bar
000000000000065d T bar
0000000000000669 T do_bar
000000000000064a T foo
```

(`T` = defined function symbol).

Equally, `foo` and `bar` might be defined in the same shared library:

```
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c foo.c bar.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o
```

and then this linkage:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
./libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `do_bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

fails just as before, and is fixable in the same way:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o do_bar.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ ./prog
foo
```

When we link the shared library `libfoobar.so` rather than the object
file `foobar.o`, our `prog` has a different symbol table:

```
$ nm prog | grep -e foo -e bar
00000000000007aa T do_bar
             U foo
```

This time, `prog` does not contain definitions of either `foo` or `bar`. It
contains an undefined reference (`U`) to `foo`, because it calls `foo`, and of
course that reference will now be satisfied, at runtime, by the definition in `libfoobar.so`.
There's not even an undefined reference to `bar`, nor should there be, since the program
never calls `bar`.

But still, `prog` contains *the definition* of `do_bar`, which is now unreferenced
from all functions in the symbol table.

This echoes your own SSCCE, but in a less convoluted way. In your case:

- The object file `libsub.a(shared2.o)` is
  linked into the program to provide definitions for `func2a` and `func2b`.
- Those defintions must be found and linked because they are referenced, respectively, in the definitions of `Client_func2a`
  and `Client_func2b`, which are defined in `libcshared.so`.
- `libcshared.so` must be linked to provide a definition of `Client_func1a`.
- A definition of `Client_func1a` must be found and linked because it is
  referenced from the definition of `func1a`.
- And `func1a` is called by `main`.

That's why we see:

```
$ nm main | grep func2
                 U Client_func2a
                 U Client_func2b
00000000004009f7 T func2a
0000000000400a30 T func2b
```

in the symbol table of your program.

It is is not at all unusual for definitions to be linked into a program for
functions that it does not call. It usually happens in the way we we've seen: the linkage,
recursively resolving symbol references starting with `main`, discovers that it needs a definition
of `f`, which it can only get by linking some object file `file.o`, and with `file.o`
it also links a definition of function `g`, which is never called.

What *is* rather odd is to end up with a program like your `main` and like my last version of `prog`,
which contains a definition of an uncalled function (e.g `do_bar`) that is linked to resolve
references from the definition of another uncalled function (e.g. `bar`) that is *not* defined in the program.
Even if there are redundant function definitions, usually we can chain them back to one or more
object files in the linkage where the *first* redundant definitions are pulled in along with
some necessary defintions.

This oddity is caused, in a case like:

```
gcc -o prog main.o do_bar.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

because the first redundant function definition that must be linked (`bar`) is
provided by linking a *shared library*, `libfoobar.so`, while the definition of `do_bar`
that is demanded by `bar` is *not* in that shared library, or any other shared library,
but in an *object file*.

The definition of `bar` that's provided by `libfoobar.so` will stay there when the
program is linked with that shared library. It won't be physically linked into the
program. That's the nature of dynamic linkage. But any object file required by the
linkage - whether it's a free-standing object file like `do_bar.o` or one
that the linker extracts from an archive like `libsub.a(shared2.o)` - can only be
linked physically into the program. So the redundant `do_bar` appears in the
symbol table of `prog`. But the redundant `bar`, which explains why `do_bar` is there,
*isn't* there. It is in the symbol table of `libfoobar.so`.

When you discover dead code in your program, you might like the linker to be smarter.
Usually, it *can* be smarter, at the cost of some extra effort. You need to ask it to *garbage-collect sections*,
and before that, you need to ask the compiler to prepare the way by generating *data-sections* and
*function-sections* in the object files. See [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687630/1362568), and
[the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770305/1362568)

But this way of pruning dead code will not work in the unusual case where the
dead code is linked in the program to satisfy redundant references from a *shared library*
required by the linkage. The linker can only recursively garbage-collect unused sections from
the ones that it *outputs* into the program, and it only outputs sections that are input
from object files, not from shared libraries that are to be dynamically linked.

The right way to avoid the dead code in your `main` and my `prog` is *not to do that peculiar kind of linkage* in which
a shared library will contain undefined references that the program does not call but that have to be
resolved by linking dead object code into your *program*.

Instead, when you build a shared library, either don't leave any undefined references in it,
or else leave only undefined references that shall by satisfied by its own dynamic dependencies.

So, the proper way to build my `libfoobar.so` is:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o do_bar.o
```

This gives me a shared library that has an API of:

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
```

for whoever wants either or both of them, and no undefined references. Then
I build my program that is a client just of `foo`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ ./prog
foo
```

And it contains no dead code:

```
$ nm prog | grep -e foo -e bar
                 U foo
```

Similarly, if you build your `libshared.so` without undefined references, like:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC shared2.c shared1.c
$ ar -crs libsub.a  shared1.o shared2.o
$ gcc -shared -o libcshared.so cshared1.o cshared2.o -L. -lsub
```

and then link your program:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c libcmain.so  libcshared.so
```

it too will have no dead code:

```
$ nm main | grep func
                 U func1a
```

If you dislike the fact that `libsub.a(shared1.o)` and `libsub.a(shared2.o)`
become physically linked into `libcshared.so` by this solution, then take the
*other* orthodox approach to linking a shared library: leave all the `func*` functions undefined in `libcshared.so`: make `libsub` *also*
a shared library, which then is a dynamic dependency of `libcshared.so`.

Comment: Thanks for this neat answer. That's crystal clear, clearly explaining what is happening, why, and provides solution. At first I thought this couldn't be used in my complicated real context, but that another point. This definitely answers the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to get rid of unused functions, you may not need to use a shared library. For GCC, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770305/7710354). For XL, replace `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` with `-qfuncsect`. An important related topic is the use of export/import lists and visibility options. These control whether extra symbols linked into your library are exported outside your library or not. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-symbol-visibility/index.html) for more information.