# symbols in static library sometimes got linked into executable, sometimes not

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a static library which is generated from many cpp files on linux using g++. one header file contains a class which implements factory pattern

pseudo code in the header file as below

```
class Factory
{
public:
    static Factory& instance();
    Base * create(const std::string& name);
    template<class T>
      void register_class(const std::string& name);
}

template <class T>
class FactoryRegister
{
public:
    FactoryRegister(const std::string& name)
    {
       Factory::instance().register_class<T>(name);
    }
}
```

cpp file for Factory has the implementations. in another cpp file Derive.cpp, there is a class that I want to register into Factory. and I defined a global variable to do this. code as below

```
FactoryRegister<Derive> g_register_derive("derive");
```

all these files are compiled into one static library and is linked to one executable.

my understanding is that as the g_register_derive is not referenced by any code, it shouldn't be linked into the executable unless whole-archive option is provided.

the strange part is that if I put g_register_derive in Derive.cpp, it's true that this symbol is not linked into the executable. but if I put g_register_derive in Factory.cpp, it got linked into executable.

I used nm to verify the result, and there is also a line of code calls `Factory::instance().create("Derive")` which can also be used to check if g_register_derive is linked or not.

and of course if I provided whole-archive option, g_register_derive will always be linked into the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Stackoverflow tag wiki about static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)
to understand linkage with static libraries, especially the fact that by default, an object file `libx.a(p.o)` in a static library is extracted and linked into a program only if the linker *needs* it.

If the linker needs to link an archive member `libx.a(p.o)` in order to
resolve some prior reference to a symbol `foo` that is defined in that object file,
then the definition of any other symbol `bar` that is also defined in `libx.a(p.o)`
is also linked into the program - because it is part of that object file - whether
`bar` is referenced by the program or not.

So, if you define `g_register_derive` in source file `p.cpp` which is compiled
to `p.o` and archived as `libx.a(p.o)`, and your application needs to link
`libx.a(p.o)` *for any reason*, then by default<sup>1</sup> `g_register_derive` becomes
defined in your program.

If you move the definition of `g_register_derive` to
`q.cpp`, which is compiled and archived as `libx.a(q.o)`, and your application
does *not* need to link `libx.a(q.o)` for any reason, then `g_register_derive`
is not defined in your program.

---

[1] With non-default compilation and linkage options, you can remove definitions
of *unused* symbols from your program. See [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687630/1362568) and the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks, this problem has been bothering me for days.